# The angle between corresponding tangent lines on two Bertrand curves is constant

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

> The angle between corresponding tangent lines on two Bertrand curves is constant and torsions of the two associate Bertrand curves have the same sign and their product is constant

Two distinct parametrized curves $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$ are called Bertrand mates if for each $t$, the normal line to $\boldsymbol{x}$ at $\boldsymbol{x}(t)$ equals the normal line to $\boldsymbol{y}$ at $\boldsymbol{y}(t)$.

So, we have $$\boldsymbol{y}(s_1)=\boldsymbol{x}(s)+a(s)\boldsymbol{n}(s)$$
Now we have to calculate $\boldsymbol T_x$ and $\boldsymbol T_y$:

$$
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol T_y&=\boldsymbol y'(s_1)\\
&=\boldsymbol x'(s)+a'(s)\boldsymbol n(s)+a(s)\boldsymbol n'(s)\\
&= \boldsymbol x'(s)+a'(s)\boldsymbol n(s)+a(s)(-\kappa \boldsymbol  t(s)+\tau\boldsymbol  b(s))\\
&=\boldsymbol  x'(s)-\kappa a(s)\boldsymbol  t(s)+a'(s)\boldsymbol n(s)+\tau a(s)\boldsymbol  b(s)\\\\
\boldsymbol T_x&=\boldsymbol x'(s)
\end{align}
$$
Now, consider, $\boldsymbol T_x . \boldsymbol T_y=\|\boldsymbol T_x\|\|\boldsymbol T_y\|\cos\theta$. But from this, I couldn't see the angle $\theta$ is constant. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First: Even if $x$ is parametrized by arclength $s$, it is most unlikely that $y$ will be. You need to use the fact that the normal of $y$ is (up to sign) the normal of $x$. Also, who taught you to write $f(t)’$ instead of $f’(t)$?

Comment: I don't really understand where I should use the fact $\boldsymbol n=\boldsymbol n_1$ here @TedShifrin And I scan the latex code from my hand writing using Mathpix. I didn't saw the prime was misplaced. Thanks

Comment: For starters, how are $y’$ and $n$ related?

Comment: Aha, I should use $$\frac{d\boldsymbol y}{ds_1}=\frac{d\boldsymbol x}{ds}\frac{ds}{ds_1}+\boldsymbol n\frac{da}{ds_1}+a\frac{d\boldsymbol n}{ds}\frac{ds}{ds_1}$$ then $\boldsymbol t_1.n=\boldsymbol t_1.n_1=\frac{da}{ds_1}\implies \frac{da}{ds_1}=0$ @TedShifrin But what will be the next move? I couldn't guess that.

Comment: $a$ is a function of $s$, not $s_1$. So $a$ is constant. Surely that is important.

Comment: I guess using the fact that $a$ is constant, I can conclude only that $\boldsymbol t_1$ is a linear combination of $\boldsymbol t$ and $\boldsymbol b$. @TedShifrin